# Quiver plot on a map with python

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to plot coloured vectors onto a map in python 2.7.
I can plot the vectors and their colours with no problem but as soon as I try add the coastline things go wrong. Please help

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

filename = 'wg_weather1_fixed.csv'
readcsv = pd.read_csv(filename)

temp = readcsv.Temperature_degC
wind_speed_kt = readcsv.Wind_Speed_kt
Wind_Direction = readcsv.Wind_Direction
lat = readcsv.Latitude
lon = readcsv.Longitude


Wind_speed_2 = wind_speed_kt*1.852

# extract U and V components
WG_wind_U = Wind_speed_2 * np.sin((360-Wind_Direction)*np.pi/180)
WG_wind_V = -Wind_speed_2*np.cos((360-Wind_Direction)*np.pi/180)

m = Basemap(projection='merc',llcrnrlat=-32.2,urcrnrlat=-29,\
           llcrnrlon=30,urcrnrlon=33,lat_ts=5,resolution='i')

# Create colour bar
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize()
norm.autoscale(temp)
cm = matplotlib.cm.CMRmap

sm = matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cm, norm=norm)
sm.set_array([])

# Plot
q = m.quiver(lon,lat,WG_wind_U,WG_wind_V,color=cm(norm(temp)))

plt.xlabel('Longitude')
plt.ylabel('Latitude')
plt.quiverkey(q,0.9, 0.05, 30, r'$30 \frac{Kp}{h}$',labelpos='W',fontproperties={'size': 15,'weight': 'bold'})
cbar = plt.colorbar(sm)

plt.show()
```

Essentially I need to add a coastline to this plot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0SX5.png)

Comment: Can you post an example of your csv file? Very hard to help without some sample data that [recreates the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi Ken - I managed to figure out where I went wrong. I had to meshgrid the coordinates and index them when I created the plot. Thanks for responding to my post.

Comment: Feel free to add what you did as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

# Read in data from CSV
filename = 'wg_weather1_fixed.csv'
readcsv = pd.read_csv(filename)

temp = readcsv.Temperature_degC
wind_speed_kt = readcsv.Wind_Speed_kt
Wind_Direction = readcsv.Wind_Direction
lat = readcsv.Latitude
lon = readcsv.Longitude

Wind_speed_2 = wind_speed_kt*1.852 # Convert from knots to KpH

# extract U and V components
WG_wind_U = Wind_speed_2 * np.sin((360-Wind_Direction)*np.pi/180)
WG_wind_V = -Wind_speed_2*np.cos((360-Wind_Direction)*np.pi/180)

m = Basemap(projection='merc',llcrnrlat=-30.2,urcrnrlat=-29,\
          llcrnrlon=30.8,urcrnrlon=32.2,lat_ts=5,resolution='i')

# Grid the co-ordinates
X,Y = np.meshgrid(lon,lat)
lons,lats = m(X,Y) # convert the co-ordinates to fit on the map

# Create colour bar
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize()
norm.autoscale(temp)
cm = matplotlib.cm.CMRmap # selecting the colourmap

sm = matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cm, norm=norm)
sm.set_array([])

# Plot
q = m.quiver(lons[0,:],lats[:,0],WG_wind_U,WG_wind_V,color=cm(norm(temp)))

m.fillcontinents(color='#cc9955', zorder = 0)

# Latitudes
parallels = m.drawparallels(np.arange(-30.2,-29.,0.5))
m.drawparallels(parallels,labels=[True,False,False,True])
# Longitudes
meridians = m.drawmeridians(np.arange(30.8,32.2,0.5))
m.drawmeridians(meridians,labels=[True,False,False,True])

#plt.xlabel('Longitude')
#plt.ylabel('Latitude')
plt.quiverkey(q,0.9, 0.05, 30,'30 KpH',labelpos='W')
cbar = plt.colorbar(sm)
cbar.set_label('Air Temperature')
plt.title('Wind velocity shaded by air temperature') 

plt.show()
```